# Create an outline ( on categories ) contained by a frame - LOTUS NOTES 7

Tags: lotus-notes

mates! I'm new in programming in lotus notes and I have a question.

I want to create an outline based on categories such as: Sorting people after their names, their birthdate and by their phone number. Could everyone explain me how to do this? Should I create an embedded outline ? This outline should be contain on a frame. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally you would create a frameset that defines the layout of your application's frames, and then set one of those frames to display a page, which in turn contains the outline.  The target of the outline frame would be a main frame where you show the views -- the selected outline node defines which view to show.

You need to create several views, one for each "sort by" you described if you want there to be a  link to each sorted view.  Your outline would then contain entries for each view.  As an alternative, you could create just one view and make the column headers allow sorting provided you can show all the necessary columns in one view.

Comment: I think the OP is asking if he could put the view contents into an outline, so it might be helpful to revise the answer to explain what an outline is and how that relates to views.